# How to change any shape (ex rectangle ...) Fill using Inline IF

Tags: wpf, inline, fill, imagebrush

I try this code bellow, but without any result, could you please tell my why?
I have a rectangle shape in WPF C#, which’s filled with an imagebrush as you see, and I used inline if, but it doesn’t worked as I planed…

```
Rec1.Fill = Rec1.Fill == (new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@”C:\1.png”, UriKind.Relative)))
    ? (new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@”C:\2.png”, UriKind.Relative)))
    : (new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@”C:\1.png”, UriKind.Relative)));
```

Note that:
Rec1 is my Rectangle;
ImageBrush source is 1.png and I want it to be changed to 2.png
That’s all I want…
but it doesn’t worked..
could you please tell me why?

Comment: The result of the comparison `Rec1.Fill == new ImageBrush(...)` is always false, because you are comparing against a new object. Keep both ImageBrushes as class members and write something like: `Rec1.Fill = Rec1.Fill == ib1 ? ib2 : ib1;`

Comment: Also be aware that `C:\1.png` is not a relative path, so `UriKind.Relative` is wrong.